# How to make sure that multiple elements of same class have been loaded on page using watir?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, web-testing

I am using cucumber and watir. The question is in reference to the code below:

```
When(/^I click on all 'Show more'$/) do
  @browser.links(:class, "more-matches").each do |d|
     if d.text == "Show more"
      d.click
     end
  end
end
```

Now, when the test case reaches this step-definition, the test case is shown as passed without clicking on all the links captured using @browser.links(:class, "more-matches").
The particular code does not get implemented may be because the ajax call has not been completed yet and the array holds zero elements and does not loop through. The code works if I introduce a `"sleep 2"` at the beginning of this step definition. Can anyone tell me how to handle this case by adding a code so that the ajax call has completed and the array holds all the elements and loops successfully. I have also tried adding the code:

```
if @browser.execute_script('return jQuery.active').to_i == 0
```

but it did not work as well.
Kindly suggest a way that the step definition gets executed and does not pass because of empty array.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Element#wait_until_present**

Usually, you would know how many links should be present. Therefore, you could wait until the expected number of links are present.

```
When(/^I click on all 'Show more'$/) do
  # Wait for the expected number of links to appear
  #  (note that :index is zero-based, hence the minus 1)
  expected_number = 5
  @browser.link(:class => "more-matches", 
    :index => (expected_number-1)).wait_until_present

  # Click the links
  @browser.links(:class, "more-matches").each do |d|
    if d.text == "Show more"
      d.click
    end
  end
end
```

If you do not know how many links are expected, it makes it a bit more difficult to ensure consistency. However, you might be able to get away with just checking that at least one link is present. Hopefully if one is present, all of the others are present.

```
When(/^I click on all 'Show more'$/) do
  # Wait until at least one link appears
  @browser.link(:class => "more-matches").wait_until_present

  # Click the links
  @browser.links(:class, "more-matches").each do |d|
    if d.text == "Show more"
      d.click
    end
  end
end
```

**Using Browser#wait_until**

An alternative approach is to use `wait_until`. The waiting for at least 5 links can be re-written as:

```
When(/^I click on all 'Show more'$/) do
  # Wait for the expected number of links to appear
  expected_number = 5
  @browser.wait_until do
    @browser.links(:class => "more-matches").length >= expected_number
  end

  # Click the links
  @browser.links(:class, "more-matches").each do |d|
    if d.text == "Show more"
      d.click
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: wait_until_present method does not work for multiple elements, it throws an error:  undefined method `wait_until_present' for #<Watir::AnchorCollection:0x00000003247888> (NoMethodError). Please suggest how to add wait_until_present for a collection such as links, divs etc.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It should be a singular link. Code updated.

Comment: Is there a way to apply any wait method for a collection of elements as in the above casesuch as links, divs, etc ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to wait for in the collection of elements? The Element#wait_until_present is already waiting on the collection (at least in the sense of waiting for the collection to be a certain size. I added an alternative approach of using Browser#wait_until, which might be what you are asking for.